# out of memory exception with grid in scrollviewer

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory, grid

I am very new in developing apps with C# for WP 8.1 Silverlight.
I developed an app to display data from a csv-file.
The data is displayed in a grid within a scrollviewer element with 7 columns.
All works fine. But when the app gets more then 600 lines from the csv-file the app crashes with an out of Memory exception.
How can I avoid this? It should be no problem to display 600 lines of text in a grid.

See my code:

```
//insert lines:
//Row create:   

reihe1 = new RowDefinition();
reihe1.Height = new GridLength(zeilenhoehe);
grid_umsatzdetail.RowDefinitions.Add(reihe1);
reihe1 = null;

//Columns create:
//first column date:
textblock_name = dateizeile + "|" + index_daten + "|" + "0";
TextBlock textblock_new_datum = new TextBlock();
textblock_new_datum.Name = textblock_name; 
textblock_new_datum.Height = zeilenhoehe;
textblock_new_datum.Width = Double.NaN;
textblock_new_datum.FontSize = schriftgroesse;
textblock_new_datum.Text = " " + teile[0] + " ";

Grid.SetRow(textblock_new_datum, zaehler_reihe);
Grid.SetColumn(textblock_new_datum, 0);
grid_umsatzdetail.Children.Add(textblock_new_datum);
textblock_new_datum = null;

//border insert into grid:
rand = new Border();
rand.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
rand.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
rand.Width = Double.NaN;
rand.Height = zeilenhoehe_head;
Grid.SetRow(rand, zaehler_reihe);
Grid.SetColumn(rand, 0);
grid_umsatzdetail.Children.Add(rand);
rand = null;

//second column amount:
... same coding as above for every column ...
```

I am really happy for any tips!

Comment: You need to keep in memory only the current rows displayed, not the entirely dataset. On scroll event, retrive the next or previous page as needed.

Comment: isn't his the job of the scrollviewer element?

Comment: I'm not a silver light expert, sorry.

Comment: @rlaengst, No not the job of the scroll viewer. You need to use a control that allows for virtual panels.

Comment: Do you have an idea which one to use?